# Can you damage a POE camera by plugging it quickly into a PoE switch over and over

Tags: power-over-ethernet

Here is the context as I am a newbie at this - I got a free HP procurve 24 port POE switch from a nearby university. I have 12 cameras and long story short only 4 of the ports worked and the unit flashes stating their is a POE fault. I tested the unit by plugging in a live single camera connection into each port 1-24 rapidly to see which ports would show activity and which ports do not. Now that camera does not work. Its a Ubiquiti G3 bullet.

I wanna know if plugging in a ethernet connection rapidly into each port could cause damage to the camera.

I would like to understand why if possible, thanks

Comment: Certainly plausible, even when only considering software issues. It is easy to produce devices with design flaws resulting in non-atomic updates to essential configuration files. I suspect I bricked a similar IoS device through such bug.

Comment: Normally it should not, but as ANX tells, it might be a software bug, try to reset the device and try it to power after 24h disconnecting on a other power supply - else File warrant on these.

Comment: Just to clarify. There are specific PoE-testing devices, and those are quite cheap. These naturally designed to check switches and to be rapidly connected and disconnected to ports.

Answer (score 2):

> plugging in a live single camera connection into each port 1-24 rapidly ... Now that camera does not work.

That is possible. An IP camera is also a computer and needs to boot up on power on. If you repeatedly disturb that process it's possible that the settings have been corrupted. Try to reset the camera to factory default if there is [such a procedure](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/204959464-UniFi-Video-How-to-Reset-a-Camera-to-Factory-Default-Settings).

Continuously and rapidly switching on and off any electronic device is a bad idea. You can damage the power supply, settings, mechanics, etc.